# Using pointer vector to reference vector is illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++98

I have one question.
Is it ok to use pointer vector as reference vector?

```
Struct Child
{
    int n;
    void func(int _n) 
    { 
        n = _n;
    };

}

struct Parent
{
    std::vector<Child> vec;    
}

void func(Parent* p)
{
    std::vector<Child>& ref = p->vec;  // is this ok?
    int value = 10;
    ref[0].func(value); // is this ok?
}

int main()
{
...
...
    Parent p;
    func(&p);
...
...


    return 0;
}
```

compiler gcc 4.4.7 (under c++11)
I guess, would it be okay if changed the value of the reference?

```
ref[0].func(value)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to comile the code? If so, did the compiler produce any warning or error messages?

Comment: You define `ref` to be a reference to a ***vector*** of `Child` structures. `ref` is itself not a `Child` or a reference to a specific `Child`.

Comment: Also note that references and pointers are two very different things. And that you don't pass a pointer to `::func`.

Comment: @R Sahu It’s example code. ref-> is wrong ref.func is right

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

There was a mistake in the code.

I was wondering if there was a problem casting just a pointer to a reference.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to fix typos made when writing the question. There's a link for it right below the tags. This is also one of the reasons you should create a proper [mcve] that you *copy-paste* into the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
I Corrected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<Child>& ref = p->vec;  // is this ok? yes
int value = 10;
ref->func(value); // is this ok? no
```

ref is not a pointer so you cannot use the member access operator ->

ref is a vector, so you need to pick which Child you want to use.

```
ref[ child_index ].func(value);
```

Comment: std::vector<Child>& ref = p->vec;  // is this ok? yes


If so, is this code okay?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with that line. You are creating a reference to vec.

Answer (score 0):

reference is nothing else but another name of an object. So these are all the same:

```cpp
std::vector<Child>& ref = p->vec;
std::vector<Child>& vecAlias = ref;
int value = 10;
ref[0].func(value);
vecAlias[0].func(value);
p->vec[0].func(value);
```

You can't change a value of a reference. Uninitialized referenced don't exist.  Once it's initialized there is no way of changing it.
Pointers on the other hand have similar purpose: they allow access to the same data from different places. You can always change what a pointer points to. But pointers are also more error-prone as then can be uninitialized or null-initialized. So try to stick to references if you don't need this flexibility.